# Finding position of non empty matrix entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a series of circles in space and I am trying to find the intersections of a given line and the circles and storing that in an array using `Table`. As the line will not intersect all circles the array has a number of empty entries

eg

```
int = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}}
```

I am aware of `Position` and `Cases` and have had some success with something like:

```
Cases[int, Except[{}]]
```

But I cant figure out how to combine that with `Position` to find the position of the non empty entries in the `int` matrix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this all you need?:

```
Position[int, {__}, 1]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {4}}
> ```

Comment: Yes this is exactly the thing, excellent, you are in fact a wizard. Thanks. I can't vote you up unfortunately because "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @Whose I am glad I could help.  Nevertheless this is probably too simple a question I will likely be closed.  Please understand that I don't mean that to be insulting; *Mathematica* takes some getting used to and the pattern behavior can be subtle and complicated.

Comment: Just for the record, the OP's pattern `Except@{}` is actually a shade faster than `{__}`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner and `Transpose@{Pick[Range@Length@int, Unitize[Length /@ int], 1]}` will be faster yet...

Comment: @Martin I default to using positive patterns as they reduce the likelihood of errors.  In this very case using `Position[int, Except@{}, 1]` is incorrect because `Heads -> True` is the default and `Except@{}` will match `List`.

Comment: @rasher I would use `SparseArray[Length /@ int]["NonzeroPositions"]` myself for that goal. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Lol - I *always" forget about SA properties...

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}};
```

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
p = SequencePosition[list, {Except @ {}}][[;; , 1]]
```

{2, 4}

```
list[[p]]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

With

```
int = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}}
```

we do

```
Values[KeyDrop[PositionIndex[int], Key[{}]]]
```

to get

> `{{2}, {4}}`

```
WolframLanguageData["KeyDrop", {"VersionIntroduced", 
  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

> [image: v]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
list = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}};

PositionIndex[list] // KeyDrop[{{}}] // Values
```

> {{2}, {4}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `SubsetPosition`:

```
int = {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {3, 4}, {}, {}, {}};

SubsetPosition[int, {{__}}]

(*{{2}, {4}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[int, {__, x : {__}, __} :> {Last@x}]

 (*{{2}, {4}}*)
```